# Total Count using korn shell script

Tags: count, output, ksh

I have a korn script that gets users in each sever and prints number of users are using that server. But the out put i get is example:

```
server71 2
server72 2
server73 4
```

instead i would like to show total count of users
example:

```
total users in all servers is 8
```

any idea or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the lines are in input.txt:

```
server71 2
server72 2
server73 4
```

With awk:

```
awk '{ total += $2 } END { printf "Total users in all servers is " total }' input.txt
```